# R binance API Get Account Request

Tags: r, binance

I have a been trying to run a Binance Get request to retrieve account information from the Binance API. When i run my code i am getting a HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request back from the server.

Here is my code:

```
timestamp <-as.character(jsonlite::fromJSON(content(GET("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/time"), "text"))$serverTime + 999)
recvWindow <- '1000000000000000000000000'

postmsg <- paste0("timestamp=", timestamp, "&recvWindow=", recvWindow)
signature <-openssl::sha256(postmsg, key="MY SECRET KEY")


url<-"https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account"


GET(
  url,
  add_headers("X-MBX-APIKEY" = "MY PUBLIC KEY"),
  query=list("timestamp"=timestamp, "recvWindow"=recvWindow, "signature"=signature),
  verbose()
)
```

Any help would be kindly accepted.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? And if so could you please post the code?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I noticed is that your recvWindow is really big. As of 15/09/2019, the maximum value for recvWindow is now 60000 or else it throws error -1131 BAD_RECV_WINDOW. Binance now recommends a recvWindow of 5000 or less. Perhaps the size of your recvWindow was causing an error when you asked the question.

Anyway, I found this code to work for me. It returns account information as a list and the account balances as a data frame.

```
##### Libraries #####
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(digest)

##### URLS #####
timestamp_url <- "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/time"
account_url <-"https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account"

##### Keys #####
public_key <- "paste_your_public_key_here"
secret_key <- "paste_your_secret_key_here"

##### Parameters #####
recvWindow <- 5000 

##### Timestamp function #####
getTimestamp <- function(){
  
  return(as.character(fromJSON(content(x = GET(timestamp_url),
                                       type = "text",
                                       encoding = "ISO-8859-1"),
                               flatten = TRUE)$serverTime + 999))
}

##### Request #####

query <- list(recvWindow = recvWindow,
              timestamp = getTimestamp())

signature <- hmac(key = secret_key,
                  object = paste(names(query), query, sep = "=", collapse = "&"),
                  algo = "sha256")

get <- GET(account_url,
           add_headers("X-MBX-APIKEY" = public_key),
           query = c(query, signature = signature),
           verbose())

content <- content(x = get,
                   type = "text",
                   encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

AccountInfo <- fromJSON(content,
                        flatten = T)

AccountBalance <- AccountInfo$balances
```

Comment: I know this is a seasoned post, but this works only partially for me. I have 22 assets in my binance account, but the code above finds only 9. Exactly the same result as with the binancer package. Any idea if binance has changed its API meanwhile? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong signature and may be you forgot about "?" after account, signature inputs for Account Info are:

```
sha256("timestamp=yourTimestamp", key="YOUR SECRET KEY")
```

And you can try URL without 'recvWindow' parameter at all:

```
https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account?timestamp=timestamp&signature=signature
```