# R and Binance API; retrieve staking information

Tags: r, binance

At the link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70270748/2952838

I see some code dating back to 2021 to retrieve info about the balance of your account in binance (you need your public and secret API for that).

However, the code fails to retrieve my staked assets.
I believe the issue can be solved since a couple of years after that post Binance did publish some info about how to get staking asset info

https://docs.binance.us/?shell=#get-staking-asset-information

but I am not API guru and I did not get very far.
Can anyone add this feature to the code in the first link of this post?